# Help needed with an optimisation problem using Kuhn-Tucker-Karush

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Maximise

$ y_1 + y_2 + y_3 $ subject to

$ y_1 +2y_3 \leq 1 $

$2y_1 + y_2 \leq 1 $

$2y_2 + y_3 \leq 1 $

$ y_1 \geq 0 , y_2 \geq 0, y_3 \geq 0 $

How would I do this with three constraints?

Comment: The KKT conditions are necessary, not sufficient. Solve the LP using your favorite method then check that the conditions are satisfied (primal and dual feasibility, complementary slackness).

Comment: @SeanRoberson For linear programming problems, the KKT conditions are necessary and sufficient. (In more detail, a vector $x$ is primal optimal if and only if there exists a vector $z$ such that $x$ and $z$ together satisfy the KKT conditions.) In any case, a necessary condition can be useful for solving optimization problems on paper by providing a handful of possible solutions, which can be inspected individually to find a minimizer. (A similar strategy is used in calculus when we minimize $f$ by first setting $f'(x) = 0$ to find critical points.)

Comment: @littleO You're right, I totally forgot that. I just couldn't find my notes from my LP class when we talked about it briefly. Of course, I'll remember this for NLP as well.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

- Sum up the three inequalities, you should get an upper bound.
- Prove that the upper bound is attainable by symmetry.

Remark:

If you insist to solve this using KKT, sure, there is almost no different from $2$ constraints, you just have more langrange multiplier.

Edit:

Dual problem is

$\min p_1 + p_2 + p_3$

subject to

$p_1 + 2p_2 \ge 1$

$p_2 + 2p_3 \ge 1$

$2p_1 + p_3 \ge 1$

$p_1 \ge 0, p_2 \ge 0, p_3 \ge 0$

Comment: yes, because its the only method I know, do I take the non-negativity restrictions as constraints as well? so Should I end up with 6 Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: I usually treat signed constraint separately. I have provided the dual problem, you might want to try complementary slackness condition though I believe that solving by observations is much simpler.